# Error on executing sql statement using CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a SQL statement as string in a variable and it supposedly return a new column as Deadline_week_test but it wrongly refer to the column name from statement

```
DECLARE @ColName varchar(max) = 'Deadline'

DECLARE @test_column varchar(max) = 'CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART("dw",'+@ColName+') = 1 THEN "Sunday" 
    WHEN DATEPART("dw",'+@ColName+') = 2 THEN "Monday" 
    WHEN DATEPART("dw",'+@ColName+') = 3 THEN "Tuesday" 
    WHEN DATEPART("dw",'+@ColName+') = 4 THEN "Wednesday" 
    WHEN DATEPART("dw",'+@ColName+') = 5 THEN "Thursday" 
    WHEN DATEPART("dw",'+@ColName+') = 6 THEN "Friday" 
    WHEN DATEPART("dw",'+@ColName+') = 7 THEN "Saturday" 
    ELSE "NULL" END AS Deadline_week_test '

    
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max) = ('select '+@test_column+'from dbo.SalesHeader');

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datepart first parameter doesn't need quotes. Also for the week day replace double quote with two single quotes.

```
DECLARE @ColName varchar(max) = 'Deadline'

DECLARE @test_column varchar(max) = 'CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(dw,'+@ColName+') = 1 THEN ''Sunday''
    WHEN DATEPART(dw,'+@ColName+') = 2 THEN ''Monday''
    WHEN DATEPART(dw,'+@ColName+') = 3 THEN ''Tuesday'' 
    WHEN DATEPART(dw,'+@ColName+') = 4 THEN ''Wednesday'' 
    WHEN DATEPART(dw,'+@ColName+') = 5 THEN ''Thursday''
    WHEN DATEPART(dw,'+@ColName+') = 6 THEN ''Friday''
    WHEN DATEPART(dw,'+@ColName+') = 7 THEN ''Saturday'' 
    ELSE NULL END AS Deadline_week_test '

    
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max) = ('select '+@test_column+'from dbo.SalesHeader');

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace our **double quotes** to 2 single quotes.

```
DECLARE @ColName varchar(max) = 'Deadline'

DECLARE @test_column varchar(max) = 'CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(''dw'','+@ColName+') = 1 THEN ''Sunday'' 
    WHEN DATEPART(''dw'','+@ColName+') = 2 THEN ''Monday'' 
    WHEN DATEPART(''dw'','+@ColName+') = 3 THEN ''Tuesday'' 
    WHEN DATEPART(''dw'','+@ColName+') = 4 THEN ''Wednesday'' 
    WHEN DATEPART(''dw'','+@ColName+') = 5 THEN ''Thursday'' 
    WHEN DATEPART(''dw'','+@ColName+') = 6 THEN ''Friday'' 
    WHEN DATEPART(''dw'','+@ColName+') = 7 THEN ''Saturday'' 
    ELSE ''NULL'' END AS Deadline_week_test '

    
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max) = ('select '+@test_column+'from dbo.SalesHeader');

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Explanation: Because string literals require single quotes, and single quotes inside a string must be escaped with another single quote.